# Firefox breaking page; not displaying images or CSS styles

Tags: javascript, firefox

For whatever reason, Firefox isn't liking my code. Looking at some related posts, I think it may be a Javascript issue, but I'm not sure exactly what it is. The devtools suggest that it's not having a problem actually downloading the files, but for whatever reason it's not displaying them correctly.

My test site is http://labs.halfbake.me/wp-smooth/

It works great in Chrome and Safari, haven't tested IE but I'm sure it's somehow worse than Firefox.

Any ideas what could be causing the problems with Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 30 you have this following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="http://labs.halfbake.me/wp-smooth/wp-content/themes/Breanne-New/library/css/main.css">
```

type="text/stylesheet" is NOT a valid MIME-type, use type="text/css" instead.

This caused Firefox not to load the stylesheet at all. Chrome and Safari probably account for some common mistakes in the markup.

Fixed the problem for me on Firefox 37.

Comment: That's embarrassing... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have some broken HTML which is probably causing the JS to initialise correctly. Check these lines in your markup

```
Line 139, Column 25: End tag figcaption seen, but there were open elements.

Line 138, Column 19: Unclosed element div.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main.css stylesheet tag doesn't self close at the top of the page, try adding /> to the end of every link tag.